# Render Angular 4 component with text coming in from an API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, runtime-compilation

I want to render incoming text from an API as subsequent HTML and component template. 
Most of the solutions I found here use @ViewChild to inject the components but that doesn't work for me since I need to iterate the same behavior for all items in the *ngFor loop.

This is how the code would look like:

> The template of the component rendering the incoming messages:

```
      <div *ngFor="let item of messages">
            <compile-component [template]="item.html"></compile-component>
      </div>
```

> Incoming message structure (item.html):

```
<my-component></my-component><div>Some html</div>
```

> Component to compile:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>It works</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent{ }
```

> Output would look like this:

```
<div>It works</div><div>Some html</div>
```

I am looking for the solution for compile-component here.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that via `ComponentFactoryResolver`. See angular docs about this here:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader